# How to select Row from Datagirdview and show in textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Having two forms where form 1 shows database in data grid view with 3 column : `id, name, text`.
I want to show column "text" in textbox at form 2 when I click on Button "Edit" from form 1. This is edit and delete button code :

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Delete")
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete?", "Deleting...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            }

        }
        else if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Edit")
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.Show();
            Hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So your problem is you don't know when editing in form2 is done?

Comment: @LeiYang, I have create form 2 with textbox1. So I want to show text Column to textbox When click Edit button. Edit and Delete Button I create with datagridview together.

Comment: But you did not say what problem you meet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to show the value of the "Text" column from the row that was clicked, you should be able to do something like this:

```
else if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Edit")
{
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    form.textBox1.Text = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Text"].Value.ToString();
    form.Show();
    Hide();
}
```

This grabs the value from the related cell called "Text" and puts in into the Text of the new form's textbox (assumes that textbox is called "textBox1".

Note for this event handler, the sender is the grid that was clicked on. It's also valid to reference by the property name "dataGridView1", but I think it's a little better form to use the handler's arguments.